# iPhone camera delay after taking picture in flash mode

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

iPhone camera delayed after taking picture in flash mode, I used `UIImagePicker` controller and used `takePicture` for capturing the picture, it is working well in all modes except if the flash mode is on. when it is on it is taking some time to process the image. why is this happening. Can anybody help me in this. my code is below.

to take picture i used

```
[picker takePicture];
```

after user took the picture...

```
imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissModelviewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I could not be able to solve this till now, perhaps just did some mesh up to hide this for some time.

Comment: i hope u r not calculating size of pic in bytes in your takePicture code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it takes a while to process the picture under any sitaution. In my didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo I load up a view over the top of my main view to tell the user I'm processing the image.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *picture = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(processImage:) withObject:picture];

    _activityView = [[PSActivityView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _activityView.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Processing...", nil);

    [self.view addSubview:_activityView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_activityView];
}
```

The PSActivityView class sizes itself in the layoutSubViews method and the processImage method deals with the image and dismisses the _activityView when it's finished.

Seems to keep users happy with my app.

Comment: Hi Openside, Thank you very much for the answer, i implemented the same concept right now in my app.. however, i am still not compromised in this, i want it to improve it more as like in instagram app for iphone, it is not showing the image processing in the flash more...i have no idea on how those guys covered it.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, thanks for setting this as the answer. if you could send me some screen shots of what you are trying to do I'll help further. I don't have the instagram app so am unable to relate to that.